# docker compose file set php version on drupal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal, dockerfile

Hi I was trying to setup a drupal container with specific versions of (drupal, php) and Postgres. Below is my docker compose file, how do I assign a specific php version onto it?

```
services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal:7.87
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - drupal_modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - drupal_profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
      - drupal_themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - drupal_sites:/var/www/html/sites
    restart: always

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  drupal_modules:
  drupal_profiles:
  drupal_themes:
  drupal_sites:
  db_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if an image is available with the PHP version you need, you can provide the PHP version in the image name, i.e., `image: drupal7.87-php7.4`. However, it looks like only PHP 7.4 is available for Drupal 7.87: https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/tags?page=1&name=7.87-php7.

If you absolutely need Drupal 7.87 with a different version of PHP, you can provide your own Dockerfile that modifies either the Drupal image or another PHP image with preferred configurations.